# How to get list of meaningful name upon fetching minted NFTs list from Alchemy Api?

Tags: blockchain, nft, alchemy

I am new to block chain and I am using Alchemy and my NFTs and NFT Meta Data is on "Pinata". When I fetch my minted NFTs from Alchemy API, in response I get list of "contract addresses" and "Token Ids". Is there any way to get list of meaningful names of my minted NFTs instead of ids (without using loops). OR is there a way to store a meaningful name upon minting . Any help will be appreciated.
response upon calling API :

````
    {"balance": "1", "contract": {"address": "0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}, "id": {"tokenId": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}}]```
````

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to get list of meaningful names of my minted NFTs instead of ids (without using loops).

Yes! As of July 12th, 2022 (current time) -- the `getNFTs` endpoint includes a `withMetadata` query param option that defaults to true ([see docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getnfts)).

That means that the response should include the info you might want, including:

- `title`: name of the NFT asset
- `description`: brief human-readable description
- `media.gateway`: public gateway uri for the raw asset
- etc.

See full documentation here: https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getnfts

An example response might look like this:

```json
{
    "ownedNfts": [
        {
            "contract": {
                "address": "0x0beed7099af7514ccedf642cfea435731176fb02"
            },
            "id": {
                "tokenId": "28",
                "tokenMetadata": {
                    "tokenType": "ERC721"
                }
            },
            "title": "DuskBreaker #28",
            "description": "Breakers have the honor of serving humanity through their work on The Dusk. They are part of a select squad of 10,000 recruits who spend their days exploring a mysterious alien spaceship filled with friends, foes, and otherworldly technology.",
            "tokenUri": {
                "raw": "https://duskbreakers.gg/api/breakers/28",
                "gateway": "https://duskbreakers.gg/api/breakers/28"
            },
            "media": [
                {
                    "raw": "https://duskbreakers.gg/breaker_images/28.png",
                    "gateway": "https://duskbreakers.gg/breaker_images/28.png"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                ...
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

You should then be able to do something like this to get your names:

```js
const names = ownedNfts.map((nft) => nft.title};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [getNFTMetadata](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getnftmetadata) method to get information on each NFT.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).